# Make prediction for a new data for the model trained with dummy data

Tags: linear-regression, prediction, dummy-variable

I have converted my categorical data into columns using the dummy variables. And then performed the train test split. Finally, trained the model and tested with the test data. Since the test data is already in the same format the model understands, it predicts without any issues but when I want to make prediction for a totally new data, creating dummy variables for the new data is not working well. Can I know how its generally done?
Here is my code..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('salary_prediction_usa_finance_job_v2.csv')

df_columns = df.columns

degree = pd.get_dummies(df.degree, prefix='degree', drop_first=True)
masters = pd.get_dummies(df.masters, prefix='masters').iloc[:, 1:]
prof_member = pd.get_dummies(df.professional_membership, prefix='professional_membership', drop_first=True)
df = pd.concat([df, degree,masters,prof_member], axis=1)
df = df.drop(['degree','masters','professional_membership'], axis=1)

X = df.drop('salary_per_year', axis=1)
y = df['salary_per_year']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

new_data = {'degree':['yes'], 'masters':['no'], 'professional_membership':['no'], 'years_experience':[10],'audit_experience':[4], 'IT_skill_rate':[6], 'Size_of_the_company_worked':[3]}

single_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data)
```